# order paid by credit store status set to "pending"

Tags: magento, status

In Magento Enterprise Edition 1.10 (I don't know if this works like that in later versions), when an order is placed and is paid totally by **credit store** her status is set to "pending".
I need to find out where in Magento's code this is done. I have just spent 2 hours looking for it with no result, thus I'm here asking you guys.
thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, I guess I need more coffee: this is the status configured in system > config > (sales) payment methods > zero subtotal checkout

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was stuck exactly like you ! More over, the french magento version is not explicit at all in the methods payment (The french translation is "Check of the subtotal") so you really helped me !

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time, I can confirm that same is in EE 1.12